# More Game / Apps Button Link - Apple Store

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect

I want to upload my game into Apple Store but I want to provide link for other my account games too. So that the given image page get opened of my account:

[image]

So what kind of link I require to use?

At above page, I have opened this link:

> https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/ketchapp/id528065807

But where can I found my account id?

**EDIT:**
At present no application or game exist into my newly created account. But within few days I will launch 2 to 3 games so I want they remain connected with other. So that I want to put More Games button within each game so players can redirect at my all games list page.

I hope now I have cleared my point. Please reply me for this because my few days passed for getting answer for this.

Comment: Why you want your account id? since when you open above link will open App Store with your apps?

Comment: If you check which ever ID above mentioned, that belong to ketchapp company - I want to replace ID with mine company / account. So where can I found account ID?

Comment: Just open the browser, google search "OneOfCompanyAppsName app store", open the page, then click on developer name you will open developer page at browser, then take the link

Comment: At present no application or game exist into account so I can't able to find similar page of my account. But multiple games I am uploading now so this functionality is important for me. I require to find my account ID for this solution I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending few days in research and discussion with Apple Support, at last I got this kind of reply from them. I hope this become useful to others as well.

Basically your Account ID get generated after your first application / game submitted and approved by Apple so then after you can place More Games link within your application / game.

Here is preview of their side exact reply:

[image]

I hope this become useful to other members too...